# Adding Pagination to nested array Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-10

So i'm creating a 1-1 chat app using `laravel` for `Api's` & `react.js` front-end

This function finds all the messages using `receiver_id` & `auth user id`

& then it groups the `messages(data)` by `day`

& then it reverse the array because in front-end i need to show messages from bottom to top

**My Code**

```
    public function getMessages(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "receiver_id" => "required",
    ]);

    if ($validatedData->fails()) {
        return $this->sendresponse('false', 'validation error', $validatedData->errors());
    }

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $receiver_user = AppUser::where('id', $request->receiver_id)->selectbasic()->withCount('followers')->first();
    $receiver_id = $request->receiver_id;

    $messages = Message::where(function ($query) use ($user_id, $receiver_id) {
        $query->where('sender_id', $user_id)
            ->where('receiver_id', $receiver_id);
    })->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user_id, $receiver_id) {
        $query->where('sender_id', $receiver_id)
            ->where('receiver_id', $user_id);
    })->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    // Group messages by day names and reverse the messages within each group
    $groupedMessages = $messages->groupBy(function ($message) {
        return $message->created_at->format('l'); // 'l' format returns the full day name
    })->map(function ($messagesByDay) use ($user_id) {
        return $messagesByDay->reverse()->values()->map(function ($message) use ($user_id) {
            $message->sent = $message->sender_id == $user_id ? 1 : 0;
            $message->received = $message->receiver_id == $user_id ? 1 : 0;
            return $message;
        });
    });

    // Reverse the order of day groups
    $groupedMessages = $groupedMessages->reverse();

    return $this->sendresponse('true', 'found', ['messages' => $groupedMessages, 'receiver' => $receiver_user]);
}
```

**Current Api Response**

```
{
"type": "true",
"message": "found",
"data": {
    "messages": {
        "Friday": [
            {
                "id": 39,
                "sender_id": 1,
                "receiver_id": 2,
                "content": "helo new msg",
                "created_at": "2024-03-15T06:49:57.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2024-03-15T06:49:57.000000Z",
                "sent": 0,
                "received": 1,
                "time": "06:49 AM"
            },
            {
                "id": 38,
                "sender_id": 2,
                "receiver_id": 1,
                "content": "helo new msg",
                "created_at": "2024-03-15T06:49:35.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2024-03-15T06:49:35.000000Z",
                "sent": 1,
                "received": 0,
                "time": "06:49 AM"
            }
        ],
        "Wednesday": [
            {
                "id": 37,
                "sender_id": 2,
                "receiver_id": 1,
                "content": "helo new msg",
                "created_at": "2024-03-13T14:54:47.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2024-03-13T14:54:47.000000Z",
                "sent": 1,
                "received": 0,
                "time": "02:54 PM"
            },
           ...
            {
                "id": 14,
                "sender_id": 2,
                "receiver_id": 1,
                "content": "helo new msg",
                "created_at": "2024-03-13T10:28:23.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2024-03-13T10:28:23.000000Z",
                "sent": 1,
                "received": 0,
                "time": "10:28 AM"
            }
        ],
        "Sunday": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "sender_id": 2,
                "receiver_id": 1,
                "content": "heiik",
                "created_at": "2024-03-10T13:17:58.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2024-03-10T13:17:58.000000Z",
                "sent": 1,
                "received": 0,
                "time": "01:17 PM"
            },
             ...
            {
                "id": 1,
                "sender_id": 2,
                "receiver_id": 1,
                "content": "hello",
                "created_at": "2024-03-10T07:27:10.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2024-03-10T07:27:10.000000Z",
                "sent": 1,
                "received": 0,
                "time": "07:27 AM"
            }
        ]
    },
    "receiver": {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "profile": "xyz.png",
        "id": 1,
        "about": null,
        "user_name": "user",
        "created_at": "March 2024",
        "followers_count": 0
    }
  }
 }
```

> I have tried using ChatGpt but didn't worked for me